# Comparing types of arguments passed to a function

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have the following abstractions to retrieve data from API:

- Class for storing data

  ```
  class DataItem<T> {
      data?: T | null
  }
  ```
- Function for query

  ```
  function queryData (
      fn: () => Promise<any>
      item: DataItem<any>
      transformResponse?: (value: any) => any // value - result from fn
  )
  ```

We want to use this as follows:

```
const item = new DataItem<ItemDto>()

async function request (): Promise<ItemDto> { ... }

queryData(
    () => request()
    item
)
```

Is it possible to do the following without generic `queryData` function:

1. Check that the result of the function `fn` matches the type stored in `item`?
2. If we pass a function `transformResponse`, can we check that its return value matches `item` type?
3. If we pass a function `transformResponse`, can we check that its argument `value` is the same as the type returned from the function  `fn`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a generic queryData function?

Comment: I am fairly certain that this is a textbook example of _why_ we need generics...

Answer (score 1):

No. A generic type variable is exactly the tool that will allow you to do this. The following should meet your requirements:

```js
function queryData<T>(
  fn: () => Promise<T>,
  item: DataItem<T>,
  transformResponse: (value: Promise<T>) => DataItem<T>
)
```